# induction proof of a determinant $n \times n$

Tags: matrices, induction, determinant

I have to proof the following property:
[image]

Can somebody help my with a few steps for n=n+1?
Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: Presumably you mean "for the induction step"; "for $n = n+1$" looks weird :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the matrix can be written as 
$$(a-1)I_n + \vec{1} \vec{1}^T$$
Now we will make use of the powerful Sylvester determinant theorem, we have
$$\det\left(I_n + uv^T \right) = 1 + v^Tu$$ 
Hence,
$$\det\left((a-1)I_n + \vec{1} \vec{1}^T \right) = (a-1)^n \det \left(I_n + \dfrac{\vec{1} \vec{1}^T}{a-1}\right) = (a-1)^n\left(1+\dfrac{ \vec{1}^T\vec{1}}{a-1}\right) = (a-1)^{n-1}(a+n-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

I‘m not sure that induction is the best approach.

Let $A_n$ be your $n\times n$ matrix and consider $v=[1~1~\dots~1]^T$ (the column with all $1$'s). Then $A_nv=(a+n-1)v$, so $a+n-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A_n$.

The rank of $A_n-(a-1)I_n$ is one, so $a-1$ is an eigenvalue of geometric multiplicity $n-1$. Since the algebraic multiplicity can't be less than the geometric multiplicity and $a+n-1\ne a-1$, we know that $a-1$ is an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $n-1$.

Thus the determinant is
$$
(a-1)^{n-1}(a+n-1)
$$

This has also the consequence that the matrix is diagonalizable.